# Can I pass an object by reference

Tags: c#, reflection, ref

I am trying to pass an object from an xna game into a method in an xna game library I'm writing. The object could be basically any type, both reference and value types.

The game library is for debug purposes and should print out to the screen the current value of the object passed in. It currently does this by calling `ToString` on the object but in the future the string will be formatted depending on the underlying type.

Here is the game library method that receives the argument

```
    public void AddToDebug(object obj)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        _debugTypes.Add(obj, type);
    }
```

And here is an example of using it from within the main game project

```
VD.AddToDebug(_counter);
VD.AddToDebug(_message);
```

`_counter` is an int and `_message` is a string.

The issue is that changes in these values are not reflected on screen because (I assume) they are passed by value and not by reference.

I tried adding the ref keyword to ensure they are passed by reference but that causes an error in the method calls `The ref argument type does not match parameter type`

Is there a way I can pass value types by reference without having to specify the actual type (I don't want to have to create method overloads for all value types if I can avoid it).

Any other suggestions also welcomed.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

After trying several different ways I eventually settled on the simple approach of passing a `Func<T>` into the `AddToDebug` method as shown below. I realised that, at least at the moment, I don't need the underlying value but only a formatted string representation of it.

In the future I may expand the library to automatically scan a passed in type and display values of all its members. If it comes to that I will likely use the suggestion from @Hans Passant to pass in a reference to the Class in question.

That said I will accept the answer from @Lee as it was most useful in my final implementation by suggesting the use of `Func`.

This is the code I have now and would welcome any suggestions for improvement.
Thank you all for your help.

```
    public void AddToDebug<T>(Func<T> getValue, Color? color = null)
    {
        var w = new DebugEntry<T>(getValue, color.HasValue ? color.Value : Color.White);
        _values.Add(w);
    }

    public class DebugEntry<T> : IStringFormatter
    {
        private readonly Func<T> _getValue;
        public Color Color { get; private set; }

        public DebugEntry(Func<T> getValue, Color color)
        {
            _getValue = getValue;
            Color = color;
        }

        public string ToFormattedString()
        {
            return _getValue.Invoke().ToString();
        }
    }

    public interface IStringFormatter
    {
        string ToFormattedString();
        Color Color { get; }
    }

    // Example usage
    VD.AddToDebug(() => _counter);
    VD.AddToDebug(() => String.Format("This message says {0} times", _message));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a way to wrap a variable instead of getting its current value.

You could create a wrapper which fetches the current value each time `ToString` is called, then pass a delegate from the containing class to get the variable:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> getter;
    public Wrapper(Func<T> getter)
    {
        this.getter = getter;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return getter().ToString();
    }
}
```

then in your class:

```
AddToDebug(new Wrapper<int>(() => this.intField));
```

Comment: Instead of the wrapper he could pass the Func around directly it seems.

Answer (score 5):

Your `int` does not live on the heap, so you cannot create a permanent reference to it. A `ref` reference only lives until the called function returns (to preserve memory safety). What you want is to create a reference to the *location* the `int` is stored. Your best option is probably to create a wrapper class and instantiate it on the heap:

```
class Box<T> { public T Value; }
```

You can pass a reference to an instance of that class and everyone who has the reference can read and write the value.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was hoping to use this debug library as a quick way of viewing variables, during development only, by adding a call to the method I described. Using your approach would mean wrapping all of the variables I need to view in the Box class, correct? This is not ideal as it would mean lots of code changes when the game is complete to remove all of the 'boxes'. Can you think of any other way to approach this? Would passing in a reference to the containing class along with the property/field name   allow me to access the valuetype values using reflection?

Comment: @Steve - Maybe you could use the [DebbugerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx) instead?

Comment: @Steve there is no way to track an arbitrary integer for sure. You *have* to build some indirection around it.

Comment: @Steve Have you considered using the [Watch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0taedcee.aspx) functionality of Visual Studio?

Comment: @Lee and Romoku I really want the info overlaid on the game screen so using VS debugger functionality is not an option for me

Answer (score 2):

> _counter is an int and _message is a string.

Which are .NET types that will defeat your plan.  An *int* is a value type, when you pass it to a method that takes an argument of type *object* then the int will be *boxed*.  You'll get a **copy** of the value.  Updating that copy will never have an effect on the original value, no matter what you do.

Similar story with *string*, it is an **immutable** reference type.  It cannot be changed in any way, you can only create a *new* string object from the original.  A new string that the original code knows nothing about of course.

Getting updates to be visible in other code requires *pointers*.  Pointers are pretty tricky, C# supports them well enough but creating a pointer to a variable has a lot of bear traps.  You can for example never create a pointer to a local variable and expect that pointer to still work when the method has exited.  The local variable doesn't exist anymore.  Updating the value through the pointer anyway will *corrupt* memory.  A big reason you need to use the *unsafe* keyword when working with pointers.

Pointers are already ably wrapped in C#, they are called *references*.  And are automatically used when you create an object of a reference type.  So what you should do is not just pass simple value or strings, you should pass a reference to an object instead.  A class object.  Now both your debugging code and your original code are using a reference to the exact same object.  And updates made to fields and properties of the object in one are visible to the other.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I'll be testing a few ways and will update my question with my final code.